# What should I do with my question?

Tags: support, specific-question, scope, quality-improvement

My [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552014/what-are-the-grammar-rules-for-html-tags) has been deleted. It had too many down votes anyway. (Feel free to look back at prior versions of this meta question, as I've changed it a lot given the changing circumstances.)

What I've gathered during the course of this Meta post is that my question, at its heart, is valid and good. Unfortunately, I used loose wording, and many people saw it as something it's not.

I'm starting over, and I will create the great post that comes up first on Google searches. (I might just end up answering it too.)

So I'm looking for advice on how to go about making a new question that avoids the fiery down voting and eventual death the last one fared.

I have several areas of concern:

1. People can't/don't comprehend the difference between parsing and lexing.

   - Seriously, read up on it. They're different.
2. Documentation has the answer.

   - You can argue my first attempt was poorly researched. But the documentation is a mess and I'd rather have a concise, convenient answer here...
3. Self-answering is scary.

   - I'm willing to self-answer, and I think I should have my answer ready for when I post the question. After all, everyone had the opportunity to answer already the first time around. If I do it right, it should further help people understand that I'm not looking for what they probably think I am. But I need help to do it right.

---

Succinctly, what I'm trying to ask in my question is:

What's the lexical structure of HTML tags?

Comment: My initial impression from the title was "too broad" and "unresearched."  If you can create an even more specific question/title that would probably help a lot.  First impressions can be very important.

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to the line "_I'm specifically looking for the composition of HTML tags_".  So maybe a title that communicates that you are looking specifically on the composition of tags instead of the entire grammar.  Still sounds a bit unresearched though so you'll need to probably get even more specific.  And explain why existing resource on the spec don't answer your question.

Comment: Pay special attention to that last sentence from @ryanyuyu's comment. The specs on w3.org are very explicit in how HTML should be formed. There are also myriad open-source browsers out there where you can find code that does what you're looking for already. I'm not sure how a question asking about the rules for HTML could be anything but too broad, considering the existing resources...

Comment: I agree that the question shouldn't have been downvoted that badly (and it sure shouldn't have devolved into a discussion about regexes). It did look badly researched and too broad and most people got hung up on that. But on the up side, you *did* get the links you need. If you have a specific issue with one of the specs, or can't find a specific type of information, it might be worth asking again with specific details.

Comment: @Laurel if you can point to a specific, confusing aspect of the spec then you should do so.  If you can only say "the entire spec is confusing" then your question is too broad.  Your question need to point to a specific section/paragraph/line and say "this portion makes no sense. What is actually happening here?" for your question to be on-topic.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I couldn't find the specs when I searched, even with `intext:HTML`, which still was catching the tail end of links. I don't find the spec to be particularly confusing, it's just verbose as there are a lot of irrelevant details. My point is: **I can come up with my own answer**, but I'm not going to bother until it's reopened (and preferably have a positive score).

Comment: I think your post has a lot of triggers that make it appear too broad at a glance. A lot of people will read "I don't really know too much HTML. Of course, I know how to use basic tags like <b> or <ul>" and immediately think you're asking for an HTML tutorial. A lot of people will read "parsing" and "HTML" and reflexively warn you about re-inventing the wheel, which is good advice for 99.999% of users who ask about parsing HTML, but not for someone writing a lexer. I *do* think that asking for old, deprecated versions of the grammar really is too broad. I would narrow *(continued)*

Comment: the question down to *valid* HTML 4.01 or 5. I think it would also help to explain *why* you're looking for this information: if people think you're just trying to parse an HTML document, they'll dismiss your question as too broad because you haven't shown what you're trying to parse; if they think you're trying to write a full-blown HTML *parser* from scratch, that would also be too broad. *(continued)*

Comment: So, I would axe your first two paragraphs, emphasize that you're looking for a context-free grammar (e.g. in BNF notation; keywords like "context-free" and "BNF" will weed out those people who read "grammar rules" and think you're asking about how to write HTML), and add links to [other resources about HTML's grammar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5175840) showing that you've done your research.

Comment: As a side-note, be aware that there are similar triggers in Meta posts that cause people to downvote and/or closevote and move on immediately. One of them is the appearance of being overly defensive about a downvoted post. I know the additional downvotes you've gotten since posting here are exasperating, but putting commentary about it in bold and all caps makes your post appear a little ranty and will actually trigger the opposite behavior you're looking for: people will vote without commenting. I would remove that part, since the second revision of your Meta question was fine.

Comment: You've completely changed this meta question, thereby nullifying the existing answer. Please don't do that. If you have a new question, ask a new question. You can refer back to this question (preferably the previous revision), but it should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I already notified the answerer. The previous version of my q was very attached to the SO question that is now deleted (by voters). IMHO the answer remains valid, because it's advice on how to avoid the problem with my new post.

Comment: FYI, at the time of deletion, your question had 4 reopen votes (1 shy of being reopened). It has since been reopened and currently has 2 undelete votes (1 shy of being undeleted). You can still edit it, although at -12, you're probably better off starting from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

**Revised**

Too many people come to SO hoping for a regex, or something, to parse their HTML string (usually they want to extract something from it). They are often very non-technical users who use whatever random technical word happens to float into their head. I think you just triggered too many red flags in most users' minds, but it sounds like you have a decent and specific question in mind. I'd recommend you revise your question to be exceptionally clear about what you want and add a few term definitions in to show that you have precise technical definitions in mind. I'm going to vote to reopen your question.

<strike>Stack Overflow was designed with a specific class of question in mind: mostly concrete questions primarily dealing with code or developer tools that can be definitively answered. While there's some give and take and everyone follows their own compass, your question pretty clearly falls outside those bounds. Your question is mostly historical and can't really be definitively answered using SO's system (posts aren't allowed to be that long).</strike>

So, the only way to answer your question outside of SO, or to direct you to resources outside of SO. But that's not really allowed either (for fear of link-rot, among other things that have been covered exhaustively).

It's a fine question, it just doesn't really belong here. Try asking your friends, or in SO's chat rooms, or somewhere like that. There are plenty of developers willing to help you, but this question should be closed as either "too broad" or "off-topic" for the above reasons.